# Highcharts one value per series column

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hi there is it possible to show only one value per category in the column chart in highcharts? without nulling the other values? because my categories will be dynamic so in the series it is impossible to know which values will be null. For example.

```
     var chart = {
            type : 'column'
        };

... code here

        xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Jan',
                    'Feb',
                ],
            },
```

Now in my setup of the series I am `null`ing the other data so that it will only show one value like this

```
var series =  [
     {
      name: 'January',
      data: [71, null]
    }, 
    {
      name: 'February',
      data: [null, 83]

    },
];
```

Now the problem arises if my categories are dynamic as I have said. Is it possible to use only one value without setting some data to null? Or am I using the wrong chart for this task (I need a vertical bar chart)? If so, what should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a js fiddle that specifically does this.

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/data-array-of-objects/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Green', 'Pink']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [{
            name: 'Point 1',
            color: '#00FF00',
            y: 1
        }, {
            name: 'Point 2',
            color: '#FF00FF',
            y: 5
        }]
    },
    {
        data: [{
            name: 'Point 1',
            color: '#00FF00',
            y: 1
        }, {
            name: 'Point 2',
            color: '#FF00FF',
            y: 5
        }]
    }]
});
```